# Magento CLI fails to return any output when I type magento commands like reindex

Tags: magento2, product, reindex

Magento CLI fails to return any output but instead goes exits to the next line, I am trying to execute reindex but I am unsure it is even executing.
I really need it to work because it is causing issues in the frontend products display

Normally, commands to the magento CLI return some values and responses, including composer install but now none of these come up

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the correct permissions to make the script executable?

linux:

```
chmod +x bin/magento
```

have you also tried using the absolute path to your php executable?
There's various ways to find this path such as the which command (which php)

```
/usr/bin/php bin/magento
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I reinstalled composer, then gave chmod 777 permission to the pub folder and now it's working